# How to Convert the Following string into Date Object?

Tags: java, android, string, date

I am New to Android Development.How to convert the Following string(5/31/2011) in to the Date Object I tried different ways But Couldn't get any Luck??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String dateStr = "5/31/2011";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: `For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields`

Comment: you misunderstood the parsing of year, see the javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year).

Answer (score 2):

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    try {
        Date today = df.parse("5/31/2011");            
        System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
        String time1 = "5/31/2011";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date indate1 = formatter1.parse(time1);
```

Thanks Deepak